# How to make the content of the map to switch to another location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I now use Google Maps JavaScript API, I want to map to navigate to another location on the map after initialize.

```
map = new google.maps.Map (mapDiv, mapOptions);
//In response to a user request to navigate to another location.
function goto (Lat, lng) {
  map.setCenter (new google.maps.LatLng (Lat, Lng));
  map.setZoom (13);
}
```

However, in this case the map display is blank, click on the operating controls unresponsive.

Comment: I suspect invalid value given in `Lat` and `Lng`. Latitude measurements range from 0 to (+/–)90, Longitude measurements range from 0 to (+/–)180. Try `console.log` the `Lat` `Lng` values in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it works for me... maybe something with the rest of your code is wrong.
For you to compare, here is a full working example. I hope it helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map;

            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 2,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            }

            function goto(Lat, Lng) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng));
                map.setZoom(13);
            }

            function button_click() {
                //Palo Alto
                goto(37.429167, -122.138056);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Move" onclick="button_click()"/>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```